# How much mass to make a shperical object?

Tags: gravity, mass

I was googling around for info for D&D campaign I am going to run.  I was wondering about the mass required for a object to pull itself into a shperical shape and it seems that the answer varies greatly depending on if the mass is rocky or icy or other things.  In this game the end villain is to be a necromancer whom resides on a space station floating in interstellar space.  The station is cigar shaped and super long.  The necromancer's minions have been bringing people to the station where wierd necromantic things are done and afterwards the person is dead and their body is put out an airlock of sorts.  The idea is that this has been going on for so long that the station appears, at first, to be a small rogue moon with two impossibly tall towers built on its north and south pole.  However, those two towers are really just opposite ends of the cigar shaped station and the spherical parts of this "rogue moon" and just so, so many piled up bodies. So here's the question, how long must I make the station and how big must the pile of bodies get to make it's own gravity cause its shperical shape?  Any other notes on the idea would be great too.  Thanx

Comment: This is  a question better-suited for [Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) , as hypotheticals like this one are more their purview.

Comment: Canonical size for self - gravity to become stronger than material forces and allow for segregation is around 100... 1000km diameter. Look for the largest asteroids

Comment: That's an intriguing question!

Comment: It depends on the melting point of the material: rock becomes soft like bread and then like syrup as the pressure rises, which makes it act like a droplet of water in space.

Comment: At any rate, you're likely looking at tens of millions of times more bodies than the number of people who have ever existed on Earth.